Is the first light of Genesis 1:3 the production of the divine Moshiach as the first angel?
Genesis 1:3-4

And G-d said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. And G-d saw
that the light was good. And G-d separated the light from the
darkness."

Is the light from the Light a god from the G-d?
Is there any tradition, from recently or antiquity, of the first light being the first angel and the divine mashiach?

Angels weren't created on the first day. The messiah is not divine. You've got the wrong religion here, buddy.

“Divine mashiach”? If you didn’t have the phrase “Jewish tradition” in your question, I would have assumed you somehow mistook this for a Christian site.

There is specifically a tradition, which we have recorded from a Jewish Sage, 1750-1800 years ago (and goes back much further): Rabbi Yitzchak, which teaches that the verse

כה־אמר יהוה גאלך ויצרך מבטן אנכי יהוה עשה כל נטה שמים לבדי רקע הארץ
(מי אתי) [מאתי]
Thus says the Lord, thy redeemer, and he that formed thee from the
womb, I am the Lord that makes all things; that stretches the heavens,
alone; that spreads abroad the earth by myself; [Isaiah 44:24]

means that Hashem literally created the world alone, so we wouldn't make the mistake that He needed help to do it. There were no angels even around at the time of the creation of the first light, according to this teaching.
If it is literal or not, it's very important to know this fundamental Torah principle that Hashem is One, and the only way to connect to Him is directly, not through an intermediary like an angel, or light, or even Moshiach.
In Torah tradition, Moshiach is a very righteous man, a king, and a teacher, nothing more. He will be a great teacher, who will teach us many great things about this One God, by teaching God's Torah very deeply, so we can all connect to God directly, and personally, without any intermediary.

Perhaps HaShem created the world himself, but through an intermediary agent, the first light who is his first angel, the divine Moshiach before his human life. Could this be Michael?

No, creation was done by Hashem and moshiach is a man not devine.

Soley based on the way you phrased the title of this question, I would like to bring some sources that "And G-d saw the light, and it was good" (Bereishis 1:4) is connected to Moshiach.
In Psalm 97:11, it writes:

א֭וֹר זָרֻ֣עַ לַצַּדִּ֑יק
Light is sown for the righteous

The commentary Eshkol HaKofer on Ruth 1:1 explains, using this verse, that it refers to Moshiach. Let's read what he says:

"מה להלן נולד משה רבינו ע"ה שהביא האור לישראל דכתיב ותרא אותו כי טוב הוא וכתיב וירא אלהים את האור כי טוב."
Just as there, Moshe Rabbeinu, peace be upon him, was born, who
brought light to Israel, as it is written, 'She saw him, that he was
good,' and it is written, 'And G-d saw the light, that it was good.'


אף במלך המשיח כתיב אור זרוע לצדיק הוא צמח צדיק הנקרא אור וכתיב קומי אורי כי בא אורך
Likewise, concerning the King Messiah, it is written, 'Light is sown for the righteous'— he is the Righteous Branch, called 'light,' as it is written, 'Arise, shine, for your light has come.'"

On the verse: "In Your light we shall see light" (Psalm 36:10), the Midrash (Yalkut Shimoni, Nach, Remez 499) explains that the light refers to the deeds of Moshiach, the Messiah:

"מה פירוש 'באורך נראה אור'? זה מתייחס לאור של המשיח, כמו שכתוב: 'וירא
אלקים את האור כי טוב.' זה מלמד שצפה הקב"ה באורו של משיח ובמעשיו קודם
שנברא העולם וגנזו למשיח ולדורו תחת כסא הכבוד שלו. אמר שטן לפני הקב"ה:
'רבש"ע, האור שנגנז תחת כסא הכבוד שלך, למי הוא?' א"ל: 'למי שעתיד להחזיר
אותך ולהכלימך בבושת פנים.'"
"What does 'In Your light we shall see light' mean? This refers to the light of the Messiah, as it is written: 'And G-d saw the light, that it was good.' This teaches that the Holy One, blessed be He, gazed at the light of the Messiah and his deeds before the world was created, and He concealed it for the Messiah and his generation under His throne of glory.

To clarify the above, the Pesikta Rabbasi (Chapter 36), brought down by the Leshem, says the light itself is not Moshiach, chas veshalom, but rather it was saved for the Moshiach as a reward for the good deeds Hashem foresaw that he would do:

What is meant by 'in Your light, we see light'? Which light is Israel waiting for? This is the light of the Messiah, as it is written, 'And G-d saw the light that it was good' (Genesis 1:4), teaching that G-d foresaw the Messiah and His deeds before the world was created, and He concealed it for the Messiah, for his generation, under His throne of glory.

These ancient sources indeed associate the original light with Moshiach, but not in the way presented in OP. The light is not Moshiach.
